# how to use 'container IP' as environment variable for same container

Tags: docker

As a special use case, I want to pass the container IP address in the environment variable for the same container during startup. Is it possible? during docker run?
preferably via .env file?

Thanks

Comment: Does the Container already exists when you want to pass the IP? Or do you want to pass it while creation? If second than I don't think that will work. You could consider to assign a static ip addresse on startup of the container.

Comment: Thanks Hytrax, for your static-ip suggestion. and I am looking for something during startup of container. It doesn't exist before.

Comment: Can you share more details about what you want to achieve by that?

Comment: I have an monitoring agent that starts during the container run. I want to have that monitoring agent same name as the IP address of the container. One way ovsly is to have the container name/IP in an env variable, but I can't figure out how to do it during the container run.

Comment: Can't you just get the ip with a script? What monitoring agent? Is this XY question? Write an entrypoint script, that gets the ip and exports it.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, share how your problem is related to programming - if it is not, it's off-topic here. To me, it sounds like you shoud move it to serverfault.com